# How to serve Angular app via Nginx + docker-compose with proxy pass

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm having some trouble to serve an Angular app within a docker-compose environment with Nginx.

The docker-compose.yml is

```
version: '3'
services:

  frontend:
    build: './frontend'
    ports:
      - "3001:8080"
  
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - frontend
```

The Angular app is inside the ./frontend folder and there is a Dockerfile.

The default.conf

```
server {
  listen 8080;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://frontend:3001;
  }

}
```

After build and run (with docker-compose build && docker-compose up) I'm able to access the Angular app through the url http://localhost:3001/, so the Angular (frontend) container is running perfect.
So the problem is in the proxy_pass from the Nginx. I have tried several approaches already, trying to add some rules, but when I access via the 8080 port (from the nginx) the docker-compose logs outpus:

```
nginx_1     | 2020/09/16 13:21:50 [error] 28#28: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.18.0.5:3001/", host: "localhost:8080"
```

Comment: Why does Nginx need to be a separate container? You can just get it to serve the build outputs directly (see e.g. this repo I put together https://github.com/textbook/react-ts-fe/blob/main/Dockerfile).

Comment: Because I will have other services in my docker-compose (the Angular app will consume those other services).

Comment: Ah I see. I think the problem is that you're using the wrong port, *inside* the network you need the container port (8080) not the host port (3001) - see e.g. https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/.